# On third floor vs. on the third floor

Tags: word-usage

"she lives on third floor" "she lives on the third floor"
Are both sentences correct?

Comment: And be aware that the meaning of "the third floor" differs in different English dialects, British English counts from "Ground floor", so "first floor" is not a street level, it is one level up.

Comment: *floor* is a countable noun, so it always needs an article, like *the*, or a determiner.

Answer (score 2):

No, "on the third floor" is the only correct option. You might also say "on floor 3".